# установить/подключить Spring and Spring Initializr Service в IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.6 Community Edition

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Подскажите как в окне <kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>New</kbd>→<kbd>Project</kbd>
 подключить вкладку  *Spring Initializr*, *Spring*  в IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.6 Community Edition ?

Comment: Проверьте включен ли "Spring Boot" plugin.
Если нет, то скачайте и установите.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Martynenko скачал, устанавливать в идею? подскажите как)?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html?origin=old_help
Инструкция на английском, но я думаю и так все понятно.

Comment: А в Community Edition разве есть поддержка Spring ?

Comment: @enzo вообще нет) но может есть обходные пути?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

единственный выход который я нашел это установить **IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate**. там все что мне нужно есть)